# Fibonacci - Recursion - Ruby

Tags: ruby

Here is a program about the Fibonacci sequence.  Each time the code branches off again you are calling the fibonacci function from within itself two times.

```
def fibonacci(number)
  if number < 2
    number
  else
    fibonacci(number - 1) + fibonacci(number - 2)
  end
end

puts fibonacci(6)
```

The only thing I understand is that it adds the number from the previous number. This program was taken from my assignment. It says, "If you take all of those ones and zeros and add them together, you'll get the same answer you get when you run the code."

[image]

I really tried my best to understand how this code works but I failed. Can anyone out there who is so kind and explain to me in layman's term or in a way a dummy would understand what's happening on this code?

Comment: The ironic thing here is that your image does a better job of explaining the Fibonacci sequence than most answers that I've mustered on the topic.

Comment: @Makoto's comment does not seem rude to me.  I do not think he is saying anything bad about you or your code.  He is saying that the image you included is very good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just the direct 1:1 translation (with a simple twist) of the standard mathematical definition of the Fibonacci Function:

```
Fib(0) = 0
Fib(1) = 1
Fib(n) = Fib(n-2) + Fib(n-1)
```

Translated to Ruby, this becomes:

```
def fib(n)
  return 0 if n.zero?
  return 1 if n == 1
  fib(n-2) + fib(n-1)
end
```

It's easy to see that the first two cases can be combined: if n is 0, the result is 0, if n is 1, the result is 1. That's the same as saying if n is 0 or 1, the result is the same as n. And "n is 0 or 1" is the same as "n is less than 2":

```
def fib(n)
  return n if n < 2
  fib(n-2) + fib(n-1)
end
```

There's nothing special about this, it's the exact translation of the recursive definition of the mathematical Fibonacci function.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know which part baffles you but let me try.

In the graph, a function f() denotes your fibonacci() and f(1) and f(0) are pre-defined as 1 and 0.
As f(number) comes from f(number - 1) + f(number - 2) in your number = 2,
f(2) = f(2 - 1) + f(2 - 2) = 1 + 0 = 1.
Likewise, you can get f(3) = f(3 - 1) + f(3 - 2) = f(2) + f(1) = 1 + 1.  You can proceed to number 6 in your graph with the code then you get the answer.

And do not care about people who already forget when they were the babe. It's just like convention here :)

Comment: Thank You for understanding me as a beginner. Some people are just rude and forget that they are too once are beginners trying to explore programs. All the best.